# React - Does changing an unused prop rerender a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, parent, prop

I'm new to React and I have a doubt about rerendering and I haven't found answer regarding this specific case.

Let's assume I have a `<Parent />` component and a `<Child myProp='10' />` component and that the Child component does **not** use that myProp prop in the return statement, nor anything related to that prop,  (in other words, the child will always return the same html elements independent of whatever that number prop is), I just want to use that number prop to identify that specific component to pass it back to the parent in an event handler. If that number prop changes, will the Child component rerender? Here is a simplified code example of what I mean:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      number1: 5,
      number10000: 20
    };
    this.eventHandler=this.eventHandler.bind(this);
  };

  eventHandler(argGivenByChild){
    //setState depending on which Child was clicked, argGivenByChild will be the identifier passed to the Child.
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child identifier={this.state.number1} clickHandler={this.eventHandler}/>
        <Child identifier={this.state.number10000} clickHandler={this.eventHandler}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}  
  
function Child(props) {
    return (
      <div onClick={()=>props.clickHandler(props.identifier)}> 
        <h1>Some heading</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Whenever I click any of the Child, the identifier prop will change, but the Child never uses it to visually render anything anyways, it's only passed to the event handler when it's clicked on. So, in that case, does React rerender the Child to account for the prop change, even though nothing changed on screen?

On one hand, I think there's nothing to rerender, as both the html and css remain the same (the Virtual and real DOM remain the same, don't they?), but on the other hand, internally the component is being modified, so maybe it has to rerender to reflect that change to the component, particularly in the event handler? What exactly happens in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will try to recalculate the difference and see if it needs to re-render based on the return statement

Comment: the word `render` has two meanings here. React will recursively call `render` in JavaScript, to figure out if there is a change in the vdom like @Blkc mentioned. if something in the dom needs to get updated, then DOM apis will be used to "render" on the actual screen. typically in React when people use the word render they mean the first part. So react could call render thousands of times per second and still be fast provided no dom apis are called

Comment: @azium So what you are saying is that the Child component will effectively update the number props, but it won't rerender anything to the screen (as long as it's not needed, like this specific case)?

Comment: Your use case is hard to understand to be honest. How about you code what you're thinking and update the question. Sounds like there's a better solution for what you want anyways but it's hard to tell right now

Comment: @azium Done. Added the code snippet and a brief explanation below.